# How to add exceptions in arraylist in java

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, random

I need to add exception so the numbers that already been generated cant be generated again.

So to generate a random number i try this.
I make two arraylist with 14 numbers from 1 to 14 in each:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> Numbers1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Numbers2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Numbers1.add(0);
    Numbers1.add(1);
    Numbers1.add(2);
    Numbers1.add(3);
    Numbers1.add(4);
    Numbers1.add(5);
    Numbers1.add(6);
    Numbers1.add(7);
    Numbers1.add(8);
    Numbers1.add(9);
    Numbers1.add(10);
    Numbers1.add(11);
    Numbers1.add(12);
    Numbers1.add(13);
    Numbers1.add(14);
    Numbers2.add(0);
    Numbers2.add(1);
    Numbers2.add(2);
    Numbers2.add(3);
    Numbers2.add(4);
    Numbers2.add(5);
    Numbers2.add(6);
    Numbers2.add(7);
    Numbers2.add(8);
    Numbers2.add(9);
    Numbers2.add(10);
    Numbers2.add(11);
    Numbers2.add(12);
    Numbers2.add(13);
    Numbers2.add(14);
```

then i make a Random that takes 1 number from each arraylist

```
   Random Calc = new Random();
    Num1 = Numbers1.get(Calc.nextInt(Numbers1.size()));
    Num2 = Numbers2.get(Calc.nextInt(Numbers2.size()));
```

then i make an integer that multiply the two random numbers that been choosen randomly

```
    FinalInt = Num1 * Num2;
```

then i have an HashMap with 200 Strings:

```
 HashMap<Integer, String> points = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    points.put(1, "String1");
    points.put(2, "String2");
    points.put(3, "String3");
    points.put(4, "String4");
    points.put(5, "String5");
    //And so on until 200 
    TextView textview1.setText(points.get(FinalInt))
```

If the FinalInt generate number 1 it will set textview1 to "String1".
So i need if FinalInt is 1 again to redo num1 * num2 so its not 1.

Comment: Use lowerCamelCase for naming variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set<Integer>` for storing the numbers. this will ensure that you always have "unique" numbers.

Now..

`if(Set.add(x))` if this line gives false you can undo the changes and generate the number again

for more details learn about Set in java

Comment: I dont really understand how can i use Set.So what the program do is takes two integers one from each arraylist and save their multiply as another integer named FinalInt i want this integer to be unique every time i come to this activity.

Comment: So every time i go to the activity i save the value of the finalInt in the Set by using the that?   if (Set.add(x))

Comment: @triple50 yes.. it will return true if it is added successfully else false
read the docs for more help